# Pandas read_html taking way too long in Anaconda Spyder--why?

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, spyder

I'm pretty sure this is basically an Anaconda/Spyder question, and probably a dumb newbie one at that.  Basically:  **why is my code taking SO LONG in Spyder**?

*Background*--I've been using pandas to read from Excel files (read_excel), manipulate the data, etc.  Now, I have a very large data table that was generated in Business Objects (BO) and saved as an *html* file.  (I couldn't save the BO file as Excel because that would generate and .*xls* file, not .*xlsx*, and these files often contain too many rows for .*xls* to handle.)

So I ran the code below in Anaconda Spyder, and it generated a list containing 1 item, and that item is a DataFrame representing my table (in this case, 47K rows x 5 columns).  That's fine, but **the problem is it took 1.5 hours to do it!**  Clearly there's something wrong, because I accomplished the same thing in VBA (from Excel) and it took about 1 minute.  So what am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
print('start', dt.datetime.now())
fn = r'C:\[filepath goes here]\my_file.htm'
xx = pd.read_html(fn)
print('end',dt.datetime.now())
```

I should mention that if I open PowerShell (I'm on Windows 10) and run the same code in python, it takes maybe 20 seconds, and I can get at the dataframe with this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(xx[0])
```

but obviously PowerShell doesn't have the functionality of Spyder (eg, variable explorer) and I want to do some additional data manipulation.  Furthermore, if I try to write to Excel from PowerShell with

```
df.to_excel(<filepath>.xlsx, index = False, engine = io.excel.xlsx.writer)
```

I get **NameError: name 'io' is not defined**.  So that's a pretty much a roadblock, at my beginner's level, too.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Could you share `my_file.htm` file (privately, if required) so we can take a look at it? If not possible, could you at least share a small portion of it? Without looking at your data it's not possible for us to understand what's happening in your case.

Comment: Yes, of course, and thank you...there are some sensitive data so I need to anonymise some values first, will get to as soon as possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it! I'll follow up this question then for updates. Or if you prefer to send me your data directly, you can find my email [here](https://github.com/ccordoba12).